# Código js me funciona en localhost pero no me funciona al subirlo al servidor

Tags: php, jquery, json, url

Tengo el siguiente código para implementar el plugin jQuery EasyAutocomplete en un input id="name" y me funciona a la perfección en mi localhost, pero al subirlo al servidor web no logro que lea los datos del archivo al que apunta el parámetro url

```
<script>
    var options = {
    url: "<?=base_url()?>assets/blueline/php/autocompleteCompany.php",
    getValue: "name",
    template: {
        type: "description",
        fields: {
            description: "vat"
        }
    },
    theme: "round",
    placeholder: "<?=$this->lang->line('application_created_company');?>",
    list: {
//        maxNumberOfElements: 10,
        match: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
};

$("#name").easyAutocomplete(options);
</script>
```

Solamente funciona en el servidor web si agrego el source a través del parámetro data (con formato json)

```
data: ['dato1','dato2','dato3','etc'],
```

Buscando solución por ahí leí que no era una buena práctica escribir direcciones a un archivo dentro del jQuery y que es mejor declararla como una variable, ejemplo $autocomplete_company, pero no sé cómo sería la solución, o si es otro el error.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda para avanzar con este proyecto.

Comment: Ya está resuelto!

Comment: puedes publicar una foto de este mismo codigo ya ejecutado es decir con las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador!

Answer (score 1):

Cambia  `<?= ...` por `<?php echo...?>`
Seguramente la configuración de php no tiene activado el operador corto de php.
Lo otro es usar las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador para ver que devuelve el script php, o si al menos lo encuentra

Comment: No es este el problema, de hecho en el mismo código se aplica esta short tag en el placeholder y funciona. Gracias de cualquier forma por la respuesta.